# How to restrict date using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two date field in my webpage 1- fromDate and 2- toDate. I want to restrict date on submit if the differences b/w date is greater than 7.

[image]

I have applied my script but not working...

```
   var d1 = new Date();
   d1 = document.forms["From"]["fromDate"].value;
   var d2 = new Date();
   d2 = document.forms["From"]["toDate"].value;
   if ((d2 - d1) > 7) {
       alert("Please enter valid date range");
       return false;
   }
```

Finally What I Want: if a user enter the date and the difference is greater than 7 days then it will show an alert.
Example: FromDate = 01/01/2016 and ToDate= 01/10/2016
if ToDate - FromDate then its show an alert on submit

In the above example  (ToDate = 01/10/2016) - (FromDate = 01/01/2016) = 9

Comment: What values of d1 and d2 are you getting?

Comment: it would be awesome if you could post a fiddle, somebody might be able to help you faster.

Comment: value of date fields

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
        var d1 = new Date(document.forms["From"]["fromDate"].value);
        var d2 = new Date(document.forms["From"]["toDate"].value);
        if ((d2 - d1) / 1000 / 3600 / 24 > 7) {
            alert("Please enter valid date range");
            return  false;
        }
```

1000 - 1000 ms in every second

3600 - 3600 in every hour

24 - 24 hours in every day

Answer (score 0):

```
var Start = moment([2016, 3, 25]);
var End = moment([2016, 3, 27]);
var Different = End.diff(Start, 'days')   // = 2

if(parseInt(Different) > 7){
    alert("Please enter valid date range");
    return  false;
}
```

From Document : http://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Date Pickers usually return a string formatted as MM/DD/YYYY.

This function returns a YYYYMMDD integer. It assumes dates are padded with zero when there is a single digit (e.g. 01, not 1). Usually there is a setting for the date picker to return the date zero padded.

```
function dateFormatYYYYMMDD( num ) {
  return parseInt( num.toString().slice(6,10) + num.toString().slice(0,2) + num.toString().slice(3,5) );
};
```

Then to find the difference, subtract your first date from the second date. e.g.

```
d1 = "12/01/2016";
d2 = "12/07/2016";
diff = dateFormatYYYYMMDD(d2) - dateFormatYYYYMMDD(d1);
```

In this example, `diff` holds the value `6`.

The only hitch is when the diff goes over a month end, since a month can end on different days.